# Copy range from an active workbook to a closed workbook, MAC OSX, ERROR

Tags: vba, macos, excel

User Peh gave me great code to copy data from a closed workbook to an open workbook, but now I want to do the reverse. I want to have an open workbook with formula and values I want to copy paste these as values into a closed workbook. I want to copy range `B36:K36` from the "AllData" tab in my open workbook to paste values starting in `K1` in Sheet1 of a closed workbook called "archive.xlsx".

This is my current code (from the internet):

```
Sub CopynPasteWrkBk()
    Dim InputFile As Workbook
    Dim OutputFile As Workbook
    Dim Inputpath As String
    Dim Outputpath As String '

    ' Set path for Input & Output
    fileInputpath = "/Users/cie/Desktop/macrotest/"
    Outputpath = "/Users/cie/Desktop/macrotest/"

    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set InputFile = ActiveWorkbook
    Set OutputFile = Workbooks.Open(Outputpath & "archive.xlsx")

    'Now, copy what you want from InputFile:
    InputFile.Sheets(“AllData”).Activate
    InputFile.Sheets(“AllData”).Range("B36:K36").Copy

    'Now, paste to OutputFile worksheet:
    OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    OutputFile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("k1").PasteSpecialOutputFile.Save

    'Close InputFile & OutputFile:
    InputFile.Close
    OutputFile.Close
End Sub
```

When I execute this code in my active workbook, it successfully opens up "archive.xlsx", gives me a `runtime error 9 subscript out of range` and errors out, then I see that it has selected selects `K1` in my active workbook (which is the cell in which I want to start pasting in the "archive.xlsx" workbook). What is wrong? Both files live in the same folder on my desktop.

Comment: Which line gives the error?  My guess is the one which mentions `“AllData”`, but you should tell us so that we don't have to all guess (and all guess something different).

Comment: Yes, I think it's the one that mentions "AllData"

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this answer based on my guess that the error is in the line saying

```
InputFile.Sheets(“AllData”).Activate
```

In that line you use `“AllData”` which, due to the use of "smart quotes" instead of normal double-quotation marks, is interpreted by VBA as a variable name and it uses that variable's value as an index to the `Sheets` collection.  However, you have never declared that variable, nor assigned it a value.  The `Sheets` collection accepts either a numeric or string parameter as the index, so you could have said something like `“AllData” = 1` or `“AllData” = "AllData"` and it would have worked.

My **guess** is that you actually didn't intend to use a variable as the index and you meant to use the statement

```
InputFile.Sheets("AllData").Activate
```

---

There is an immense syntactical difference between the character `"`, and the smart-quote characters `“` and `”`.  The `"` character is interpreted by VBA as the start/end of a string literal.  The `“` and `”` characters are interpreted by VBA in the same way as letters such as "a", "b", "c", etc, and therefore can be used in variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am slightly confused - did I put the line saying:

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am slightly confused - did I put the line saying: 
   'InputFile.Sheets(“AllData”).Activate' in the wrong location?  Apologies that I am so dense on this. For reference, this is the source of the code I am using: [link] (https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/783385-visual-basic-applications-copy-active-workbook-paste-closed-workbook.html)

Comment: @cwight - No, your error appears to be that you were using a variable called `“AllData”` instead of the string literal `"AllData"`.

Comment: @cwight - if you want to use the string literal `"AllData"` (as I suspect you do), use that and don't use the variable `“AllData”`.  So just edit the two locations where you used the variable to use the string literal instead.