# Run time error 9 subcript out of range and invoice automation

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run some VBA code to generate an automated invoice, but I am receiving the following error:

> Error 9 subscript out of range

for this code.

```
lastrow = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim customername As String
Dim customeraddress As String
Dim invoicenumber As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim mydate As String
Dim path As String
Dim myfilename As String
lastrow = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
r = 2
For r = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(r, 17).Value = “done” Then GoTo nextrow

customername = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 1).Value
customeraddress = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 2).Value
invoicenumber = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 6).Value
quantity = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 18).Value
Description = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 19).Value
UnitPrice = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 20).Value
SalesTaxRate = Sheets(“CustomerDetails”).Cells(r, 16).Value

Cells(r, 17).Value = “done”
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open (“C \ invoices \ BasicInvoice.xlsx”)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“I8”).Value = invoicenumber
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“C8”).Value = customername
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“C9”).Value = customeraddress
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“B21”).Value = quantity
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“C21”).Value = Description
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“H21”).Value = UnitPrice
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“BasicInvoice”).Range(“D18”).Value = SalesTaxRate

path = “C \ invoices \ ”
mydate = Date
mydate = Format(mydate, “mm_dd_yyyy”)
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & invoicenumber & “ - ” & customername 
& “ - ” & mydate & “.xlsx”
myfilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
SetAttr myfilename, vbReadOnly
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut copies:=1
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

nextrow:

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: the idea was to defind the last row of data in the worksheet

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have a worksheet called `CustomerDetails` - spelled exactly like that? Also, you didn't specify the worksheet for `Rows.Count`

Comment: Yes the worksheet is spelled correctly. how to specify Davis actually new to VB

Comment: Can you show the rest of the worksheet. Just so we know

Comment: you mean the rest of the code or worksheet?

Comment: Change all your smart quotes (`“` and `”`) to normal quotes (`"`).  Otherwise `“CustomerDetails”` is intepreted as a variable name, not the string you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy range from an active workbook to a closed workbook, MAC OSX, ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421740/copy-range-from-an-active-workbook-to-a-closed-workbook-mac-osx-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I have saved in my personal macro workbook:

```
Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

It is something that I use daily which is why it's there, and you might want to do the same if it's causing you problems

so get rid of that line completely, copy the above code to your module, then whatever you were using `lastrow` for, update it to include the worksheet.

You would call this function like this (assuming that you don't have a declaration for your workbook):

```
... = LastRow(Worksheets("CustomerDetails"))
```

---

Edit: I had to completely rewrite your code, so please make sure everything works

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Function LastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const path$ = "C:\invoices\"

    Dim customername As String, customeraddress As String, invoicenumber As Long
    Dim r As Long, mydate As String, myfilename As String, wbInv As Workbook
    Dim quantity, Description, UnitPrice, SalesTaxRate
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Dim wsCD As Worksheet

    Set wsCD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CustomerDetails")

    For r = 2 To LastRow(wsCD)

        If Not Cells(r, 17).Value = "done" Then

            With wsCD

                customername = .Cells(r, 1).Value
                customeraddress = .Cells(r, 2).Value
                invoicenumber = .Cells(r, 6).Value
                quantity = .Cells(r, 18).Value
                Description = .Cells(r, 19).Value
                UnitPrice = .Cells(r, 20).Value
                SalesTaxRate = .Cells(r, 16).Value
                .Cells(r, 17).Value = "done"

            End With

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set wbInv = Workbooks.Open("C:\invoices\BasicInvoice.xlsx")

            With wbInv.Worksheets("BasicInvoice")
                .Range("I8").Value = invoicenumber
                .Range("C8").Value = customername
                .Range("C9").Value = customeraddress
                .Range("B21").Value = quantity
                .Range("C21").Value = Description
                .Range("H21").Value = UnitPrice
                .Range("D18").Value = SalesTaxRate
            End With

            mydate = Format(Date, "mm_dd_yyyy")
            wbInv.SaveAs Filename:=path & invoicenumber & " - " & customername & _
                    " - " & mydate & ".xlsx"
            myfilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            SetAttr myfilename, vbReadOnly
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            'ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut copies:=1
            wbInv.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wbInv = Nothing
            Set tempWB = Nothing

        End If

    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: @Ken Yes, so above or below your `Sub()...End Sub`, you would need to paste the above function. Then you don't even need to declare `LastRow`, this function does it for you. If you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48336230/edit) to include your whole code (if it's not too long), I will implement my solution into it for you.

Comment: keeps saying your code not properly formated when i want to add

Comment: @K.Davis got the full code could you now impliment your code in it? waiting thanks

Comment: cheers bro you are the best works like charm. just need to do some little editing.

Comment: @K.Davis please a quick one. Now looking at the code it is going to insert just one item per newly automated books. what in a case where one invoice number contains more than one item, what do i need to add mutiple items and quantity in the new automated file.